# Call onclick attribute programatically and talk to the event parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have read the other post relating to this matter. Unfortunately it has not resolved my problem. I am happy to use jQuery, so I am looking for the cleanest solution.

I have radio buttons defined as follow:

```
 a = 5;
 input.value = "myButton";
 input.onclick = (function (a) {
      return function (e) {
          changeSelectedRadio(e.srcElement, a);
      };
  })(a);
```

I need to be able to execute this when user click on the radio button (this works fine), and programatically.

I have tried:

```
$("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").triggerHandler("click");
$("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").click();
```

Both produce the same result: e (the event parameter) does not exist.

```
$("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").onclick();
```

Does not work

Changing the `input.onclick` to `input.click` also did not work. When the use click, the function does not get triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery already, might as well build the inputs that way:

```
var input = $('<input value="something">').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this); // the element clicked, as a jquery obj
    alert(elem.attr('id');
});

$('body').append(input);
$('input').trigger('click');
```

Adjust the selectors as needed, and you'll need to actually append the elements to the DOM, but it'll work.

Comment: Hi, I dont see how you then talk to e.srcElement this way. e is the default parameter provided by the onclick function.

Comment: jQuery gives the element that was clicked as `this`. I'll update the sample code

Comment: "this" is not the same as the "e" provided by onclick. I need e to go and talk to the parent of the parent of this input. Is this possible with "this"?

Comment: `this` is simply the DOM element itself but if you wrap it with jQuery you can use any jquery methods... i.e. `$(this).parent();`

Comment: no need for jquery for simple event listeners. just use addEventListener() and use the event type you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").bind( "click", function() {
  alert( "clicked" );
});
```

Comment: why are you using jquery for something as simple as event triggers?

Answer (score 0):

What is passed to the function is a jQuery [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), not a native event. You can use the `target` element to get at the source that was clicked on or use `this` to reference the properties of the object directly.  See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/YQh3Q/

```
<p><input id="foo1" name="foo" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked"> Foo1</p>
<p><input id="foo2" name="foo" type="radio" value="1"> Foo2</p>

(function ($) {
    var input = document.getElementById("foo2");

    var a = 5;
    input.value = "myButton";
    input.onclick = (function (a) {
        return function (e) {
            alert(e.target + '|' + this.id);
        };
    })(a);

    $("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").each(function() {
        $(this).trigger("click");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Alternatively (and probably better) you can use a pure jQuery solution

```
$(function() {
    var a = 5;
    $('input#foo2').on('click', function() {
       changeSelectedRadio(this, a);
    })
    .val('myButton');

    $("input[type='radio'][value='myButton']").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: "this" is not the same as the "e" provided by onclick. I need e to go and talk to the parent of the parent of this input. Is this possible with "this"?

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent();`

Comment: you are doing a lot of work for a simple event trigger. remember KISS (keep it simple stupid)

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use **addEventListener()** you can add all types of events. example: "click", "mousemove", "mouseover", "mouseout", "resize" and many more. the false at the end is to stop the event from traversing up the dom. If you want parent dom objects to also receive the event just change it to true. also this example requires no javascript libraries. This is just plain old javascript and will work in every browser with nothing extra needed.

Also **addEventListener() is better than onClick()** as you can add an unlimited number of event listeners to a dom element. If you have an onClick() on an element and then set another onClick() on the same element you have overwritten the first onClick(). Using addEventListener() if i want multiple click events to trigger when i click on an element i can do it with no problem.

If you want data about the element that is triggering the event you can pass the event to the function. You will see in my example function(e) e is the event and you can use **e** or **this** to target the element that is being triggered. Using e or this i can also get more data about the triggered event. for example if the event was a mousemove or mouseclick i can get the x and y position of the mouse at the time of the event.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>exampe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="test" href="">test</a>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(e){
            alert('hello world');
            alert('my element '+e);
            alert('my element '+this);
        },false);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if you want to have addEventListener call a function just change the 2nd value to the function name like this.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",f1,false);
```

this will execute the function

```
function f1(){ ... }
```

When you want to remove an event listener just call target.**removeEventListener**(type, listener[, useCapture]). Very simple and easy to manage.